# Reading from a file and into a dynamically allocated array of type Student in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I thought I had a decent understanding of fstreams and struct's, but for some reason I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. The file I'm reading from starts with an integer 'n' that represents the amount of students in the file, it's then used as the size of the dynamically allocated array of Students.

I go on to read each name, major, and grade from the file into the array of type Student. But for whatever reason, it's only reading the first "line" in the file (as in it reads the first name, major, and grade), and does that n times. I messed around with the code and I believe I've narrowed the problem down to the array not actually being of size n. It correctly reads the first int in the file, as I've printed it out to make sure that's working, and I've tried manually reading in each Student for the array from the file with the same issues.

This is an assignment, so I'm not looking for any straight forward answer, but a nudge in the right direction would be incredibly helpful.

Here's my code:

```cpp
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name, major;
    double grade;

    void display(Student);
    void filterByMajor(Student[], int, string);
    void filterByGrade(Student[], int, double);
};

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile;
    Student* students = nullptr;
    string filename;
    int n;

    cout << “Enter an input file to read from: “;
    cin >> filename;

    inputFile.open(filename);

    if (inputFile.fail()) {
        cout << “ERROR: Could not open the file.” << endl;
    }
    else {
        inputFile >> n;
        students = new Student[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            inputFile >> students[i].name;
            inputFile >> students[i].major;
            inputFile >> students[i].grade;
        }

        cout << “      Student info” << endl;
        students->display(students[0]);
        cout << endl;
        students->display(students[3]);
    }

    delete[] students;
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}

void Student::display(Student s) {
    cout << “Name:   “ << name << endl;
    cout << “Major:   “ << major << endl;
    cout << “Grade:   “ << grade << endl;
}
```

And the input file I'm reading from:

```
7
John CS 3.0
Joe Math 2.5
Jane Math 3.7
Mike CS 2.2
Carol CS 3.3
James Math 2.8
Mary CS 3.6
```

Comment: Do not post image of the code, paste the code here, even better create a [mcve]. You are using methods in a weird way, you pass an argument to `Student::display` and then not use it? Why?

Comment: @Quimby I actually use that method twice towards the end of the image, all it does it print out the name, major, and grade. I'll post my actual code on here as an edit though.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but `students->display(students[3])` will print `name` of `students`, i.e. `students[0]`, not `students[3]` since it is ignored.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your reading code, it's the display method that is wrong. Common situation with beginners they believe one part of the code (display) but don't believe another (reading). When there's a bug doubt all your code, any part could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your reading code. That is actually reading the file data just fine. The real problem is in the display code.  You are calling `display()` on the 1st entry in the array each time, and `display()` is ignoring the `Student` that is passed to it, instead displaying the data of the `Student` it is called on, so you see only the data of the 1st entry being printed each time.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name, major;
    double grade;

    void display() const;
};

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile;
    Student* students = nullptr;
    string filename;
    int n;

    cout << “Enter an input file to read from: “;
    cin >> filename;

    inputFile.open(filename);

    if (inputFile.fail()) {
        cout << “ERROR: Could not open the file.” << endl;
    }
    else {
        inputFile >> n;
        students = new Student[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            inputFile >> students[i].name;
            inputFile >> students[i].major;
            inputFile >> students[i].grade;
        }

        cout << “      Student info” << endl;
        students[0].display();
        cout << endl;
        students[3].display();
    }

    delete[] students;
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}

void Student::display() const {
    cout << “Name:    “ << name << endl;
    cout << “Major:   “ << major << endl;
    cout << “Grade:   “ << grade << endl;
}
```